# Heroku apscheduler: schedule a cron job of URL request

Tags: django, heroku, scheduling

I am following [this document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python) to schedule a cron job for my Django application. The following is the `clock.py`:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from django.shortcuts import redirect

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=60)
def timed_job():
    return redirect('http://example.com/')

sched.start()
```

Heroku shows the following error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
Requested setting ROOT_URLCONF, but settings are not configured. You
 must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or
 call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I have no idea about what the error message means. My questions:

1. I put the `clock.py` under the project root directory. Is it correct?
2. How do I schedule a URL-request job?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do by returning a redirect here. Redirect is a type of http response returned from a Django view; it makes no sense at all from an external command.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I just want to schedule a URL request. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems more like something related to how your project is structured, something outside of *clock.py*. Does some basic hello world view work when you open it in your browser? Do you have a *settings.py* file in place? Also check out the [basic Django on Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) and maybe try building from there to get the scheduling to work.